# Navigation view is colloiding with app bar layout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_client_main_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_client_main_page_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Following is `app_bar_client_main_page`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ClientMainPage">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_client_main_page"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_client_main_page contains just a relative layout.

I want the navigation view to be below app bar layout but still it is colloiding with the appbarlayout.

I have even mentioned margin top in navagtion view but still it is colloiding. How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the guidelines that is how it is supposed to work: [guidelines](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs)

You can move your AppBarLayout outside the DrawerLayout and it should work, but then you will break your CoordinatorLayout functionality

Comment: its collapsing with status bar

Comment: So the drawer is hiding the status bar? Or the status bar is over the drawer?